# IIF in Proc SQL

Tags: sql, sas

I want to translate the following snippet of code for use in Proc SQL for SAS:

```
UPDATE loan_tape
SET apples = IIF(apples != 0.0, apples, 20.0)
```

However IIF() is not recognized by PROC SQL. Can I implement an if/else or some kind of CASE statement? None of that seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `case`:

```
UPDATE loan_tape
    SET apples = (CASE WHEN apples <> 0.0 THEN apples ELSE 20.0 END)
```

Actually, use `WHERE`:

```
UPDATE loan_tape
    SET apples = 20.0
    WHERE apples = 0.0 OR apples IS NULL;
```

This is the best way to do this in any database, because it limits the number of rows being updated (some databases only do the update when the value changes, but it is still better to express this logic as a filter).

I should also note that doing equality comparisons with *floating point* numbers in SQL (or any language) is dangerous.  SQL has fixed point values (`decimal`/`numeric`).  The problem is that values very, very, very close to zero tend to "look" like 0 -- something like 0.000000000097.

Comment: @JohnHC . . . misplaced parenthesis.

Comment: You've put `WHEN` instead of `WHERE`.

Comment: I would avoid using `<>` as an operator in SAS. It has a different meaning in a SAS data step than it does in PROC SQL.

Comment: @Tom . . . I believe this question is explicitly about the SAS proc SQL.  Using `<>` is handy, because the code will also work using pass-through.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks so much.

Comment: `<>` is *wrong* in SAS, unfortunately.  It is the `min` operator, not `not equals`, in SAS contexts.  It does get interpreted to `not equals` in PROC SQL (for compatibility presumably), but writes a note to the log, and in general is a bad habit (as then often it ends up being used in other places).

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the SAS `IFN()` function, which does exactly what `IIF()` is doing in your example, giving the minimal change from your starting point. As Gordon said, though, using a `WHERE` clause is probably better for this task.

Documentation page for `IFN`:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002604573.htm

Answer (score -2):

Use `case`

```
UPDATE loan_tape
SET apples = case when apples <> 0.0 then apples else 20.0 end
```